# Parsing JSON response to get body from HTML

Tags: javascript, android, json, webview

I get a following json response. How can I get the body content from it so that I can check some condition like json below:

```
{
    "googleplus": {
        "error_message": "User did not grant permission + access_denied",
        "error_code": 2020
    }
}
```

I tried following statement to get body of html but it seems to be not matching the condition in if statement

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.showHTML(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML);");


class MyJavaScriptInterface   
{ 
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showHTML(String html)  
    { 

        if(html.contains(some string from body of html))
        {
            //do something
        } 
    }

}
```

All I want is that what string should from body I use in if condition so that it becomes true

Comment: where is the body content in the above json???

Comment: @broken-heart-ღ actually I am doing google account login but while granting permission if user chooses cancel I get above html. I just want to handle this scenario. Can you help?

Comment: hi are you talking about the parsing of this given json?

Comment: @jitesh-upadhyay I get above response and I just want to get error message string so that I can make if condition TRUE

Comment: yes you can do that just parse the json which you have and get the error_message please have a look below given answer by me!!

Comment: is this sufficient to solve yours problem?

Comment: @jitesh-upadhyay give me a moment, I will give it a try and let you know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as yours json is as given

```
{
  "googleplus": {
    "error_message": "User did not grant permission + access_denied",
    "error_code": 2020
  }
}
```

parse the json data as follows

```
JSONObject primaryObject=new JSONObject(//pass yours json string here);
        JSONObject googleplus=primaryObject.getJSONObject("googleplus");

        String error_message=googleplus.getString("error_message");//use it if you need
        String error_code=googleplus.getString("error_code");
```